# Robot framework - way to set statuses of previous test-cases

Tags: robotframework

I got robot framework tests in below schema:

```
Suite Setup
Test Case 1
Test Case 2
Test Case 3
...
Suite Teardown
```

In tear down step I have got a loop that goes through all tests cases and do some additional checks for all test cases (i can do this when test cases are execute because it need to wait some time for some operations in external system). If any of this checks will fail, the teardown step is fail and it also fail every test case. I can set tear down keyword to don't fail tear down step but than I will have all pass in test suite.

Is there any option/feature (or walkaround) that will give me possibility to set status and error message of selected test case in tear down step (something like `tc[23].status=fail, tc[23].message='something'`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, at least not out-of-the-box. In any event I also think this is not a desirable test approach. Every test should be self contained and all the logic to assess PASS or FAIL should be in that test. Revisiting the result is in my view an anti-pattern.

It is understandable that when there is a large pause of inactivity that you would like to progress with your tests. However, I think that parallelising your tests is a better and more stable approach. For Robot Framework there is `Pabot` to help you with that, but creating your own test runner is possible.